# Error to execute DSC when create virtual machine in azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I create in powershell Virtual Machine Windows 8.1 in azure. And Set-Azure DSC. But I see error, during execute DSC:

> [10/21/2014 14:17:39.44] Executing: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.3.0.0\bin\install.cmd 
>   [10/21/2014 14:17:47.24] Execution Complete.
>
> #

```
 Execution Output:


 Execution Error:
 C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.3.0.0\bin\install.ps1 : File 
 C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.3.0.0\bin\install.ps1 cannot be 
 loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
 information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
 At line:1 char:1
 + C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.3.0.0\bin\install.ps1 -verbose
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

How can I enable security policy during create VM in powershell?

Comment: i can´t tell you how to enable it during the creation but you can set the executionpolicy afterwards with `set-executionpolicy`

Comment: Not sure how the script is being called but I would try to find it and change the call to something like `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.3.0.0\bin\install.ps1`